# Transferring a file over two different networks using a common access point

Tags: java, sockets, java-io

Say I have three Computers: `A,B,C`: where `(A,B)` form a network (are connected directly) and `(B,C)` are connected directly. Now I want to transfer a file, using Java Sockets from `A` to `C` (or vice versa). Can I do it directly using a normal transfer? Theoretically since they form two networks with different IP Address' scheme, creating a server socket in either of the computer will not lead to its discovery by a client socket in the other.

If it is not so, then is making `B` an intermediate host, which just buffers in and out the file-stream contains the way?

If both are equally advisable and/or feasible, then  will the first method raise security issues and the second method decrease efficiency. Please answer, from an implementational standpoint. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Second approach will definitely work (This technique is used for routing network packets to home network, the broadband that we use. But this works at network level not transport layer). Essentially you need to create two socket connections at B, one for A and other for C. Create two threads at B to handle communication with each peer (A and C). At A and C also, you need to create two threads to one for sending data and other for receiving data. Hope this is what you are expecting.

If you somehow manage to access A machine from C machine, then its you can directly send/receive data between machines. In this case also you need to create two threads two handle send/receive part of communication.

First approach is better in terms of performance if it works. But in second approach you can apply additional security checks at B before forwarding data to A. It completely depends upon your requirement.